# I am a little confused about class,instance and object. This is my understanding about the 3 kindly correct me if I'm wrong thank you

Tags: class, object, instance

```
class Person
{

    Private $name;Private $age;

        public function __construct($name,$age) 
        {
            $this->name = $name; 
            $this->age = $age;  
        }

        public function createPerson()
        {
            return "I am" . $this->name . "age of" . $this->age;
        }
}

$person1 = new Person('cj',22); // this is the instance
```

person1 will be given the name of cj with his age of 22 // this is the object

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong: An object is the instance of a class, So:

```
$person1 = new Person('cj',22);// here you create an instance of the class Person.
```

In other words, you just created an object that you assigned to the variable person1.

```
person1 will be given the name of cj with his age of 22
```

This is just the data of the object person1.